# Add object to a Terrain?

Tags: unity, terrain

It's possible to add object made by blender to unity terrain ? this object will become a part of it. I can add grass and trees on it.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of it"? Do you want it to be part of the actual *mesh*? Or would automatic placement on the map *as separate objects* suffice?

Comment: [1](http://anthonypigeot.com/content/images/2014/Jan/super_mario_galaxy_wii_09.jpg) Look, i want make a object that have all kind of terrain feature.

Comment: in other words, you only want it to *appear* on top of the mesh, much like trees and bushes.

Comment: Yes. could mesh solve this ?

Comment: terrain should have this built in. Im extremley strapped for time, so Im afraid youll have to wait before I go looking to post an answer. Someone else might beat me to it, in the mean time.

Comment: In the mean time, check the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Terrain.html), and see if there is anything useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Link and info with it from before is no longer valid/usable.

If your goal is adding things on top like bushes then you'd just want to import the model. Go to [terrains](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-UsingTerrains.html) and build your terrain as you want it. Then import your model into the scene and place it in/along the terrain where you want it. A quick/rough solution would be merging the two things together in the hierarchy or just placing the models as children under the terrain.

As for replacing the mesh, the closest thing I think you could get would be adding in a custom texture for the terrain, since you can build terrain yourself with Unity's tools and then just paint on the texture, and eventually add pre-made bushes, etc on top.

Comment: We tend to discourage answers that rely wholly on an external link. Consider editing the answer to include at least a rough summary of the information you want to highlight from the linked page, providing the link itself for further details. That way, if the linked resource ever goes offline or moves, your answer will still provide a useful signpost toward a solution.

Comment: @DMGregory I changed the answer to better fit the question I think, but I may still be slightly misinterpreting the question..